# Problem installing urg_node on ros hydro

Tags: ros, urg-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am getting this error when installing the urg_node drivers for hokuyo on Ubuntu 12.04 ROS hydro.

What I did--

1. I have a catkin_ws workspace with build, src and devel folders
2. cd into src folder
3. git clone from the urg_node github page
4. cd into catkin_ws folder
5. run the command $ catkin_make

The error I got is this

```
    -- +++ processing catkin package: 'urg_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(urg_node)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package urg_c.

  Set urg_c_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  urg_c.  The file will have one of the following names:

    urg_cConfig.cmake
    urg_c-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  urg_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

How to resolve this error. The sensor for which I am trying to install the urg_node is hokuyo UHG-08LX.

Like groovy , is there no sudo apt-get command to install the urg_node laser drivers for Hydro?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165016/problem-installing-urg_node-on-ros-hydro/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not install from debs?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2014-05-14**:
Great! this is what I was looking for... Thanks a lot for your help and quick reply.. its working now.

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2014-05-20**:
I have one more doubt, is there no urg_node drivers for ROS fuerte??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
According to the wiki page, there isn't a released version for Fuerte: http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node .